# Change the entries in an array in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell

Suppose you have

`let a = array ((1,1),(2,2)) [((2,1),3),((1,2),2),((1,1),2),((2,2),3)]`

Now I want that to multiply the 3 in the last tuple with some number. How can I do that?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Which `array` function is this?

Comment: I tried to make an accumArray, but that didn't help much. I also tried with *product(snd (unzip (assocs a)))* but then I don't know how to put the result in the array.

Comment: @melpomene the array from Data.Array, i guess

Comment: If you want to modify entries, why are you using an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wanted to multiply that by `5` it would be:

```
accum (*) a [((2,2),5)]
--     ^  ^   ^     ^
--     function to combine values
--        array to read
--            one of the indices to manipulated
--                  value to give to f for the associated index
```

The signature of this function reads

```
accum :: Ix i => (e -> a -> e) -> Array i e -> [(i, a)] -> Array i e
```

and its [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.2.0/docs/Data-Array.html#v:accum) says:

> accum f takes an array and an association list and accumulates pairs
>   from the list into the array with the accumulating function f.

So calling `accum f arrayValue listWithPairsOfIndicesAndValues` will call `f` for every index given in `listWithPairsOfIndicesAndValues` providing the old value and the value from `listWithPairsOfIndicesAndValues` for this index and return a new array with all the positions mentioned in `listWithPairsOfIndicesAndValues` updated with the values returned by the respective calls to `f`.

Answer (score 5):

There's two different ways to your goal:

1. Using the incremental update:

   `a // [((2,2),(3*7))]`

   `>>> array ((1,1),(2,2)) [((1,1),2),((1,2),2),((2,1),3),((2,2),21)]`

(Instead of 3*7, you could use your own n and refer to that same location (a!(2,2)))

2. Using the accumulation:

   `accum (*) a [((2,2), 7)]`

   `>>> array ((1,1),(2,2)) [((1,1),2),((1,2),2),((2,1),3),((2,2),21)]`

Answer (score 2):

One could use `a // [(2,2), n * (a ! (2,2))]` to multiply the element with index `(2,2)` by `n`.

(There should also be some lens-y approach with a better syntax)